# Creating Custom BigQueryHandler in Laravel

Tags: laravel, logging, google-bigquery

Hello there I am supposed to transfer artisan logs to bigquery and store it. I wrote Custom Channel

```
 'channels' => [
        'stack' => [
            'driver' => 'stack',
            'channels' => ['daily', 'bigquery'],
        ],
'bigquery' => [
            'driver'  => 'custom',
            'level' => 'debug',
            'via' => BigQueryHandler ::class,
            'with' => [
                'bq_dataset_name' => 'something',
                'bq_table_name' => 'something_com_logs'
            ]
        ],
```

I have wrote BigQueryHandler class to write those logs using write() method. I have also wrote test case which works fine and updates the record in bigquery table. but If I invoke bigquery channel from artisan files it doesnt work. Can someone tell me whats wrong here?

the command to invoke bigquery channel is
 `\Log::channel('bigquery')->info('Something happened!');"`
Have written it inside handle().

Comment: Can you  better explain what not working means and if you have any error message to share

Comment: Hi Not working means the bigquery channel isnt invoking. The data is not being stored in bigquery. But If i run the unit test it does. not getting any errors

Comment: 1) Did you implement a driver called 'custom'
2) Was your unit test calling the class directly or was it invoking the channel?

Comment: When an attempt fails, do you see any errors in the BigQuery side or any evidence that the request has reached BigQuery?